# Is there a serilog sink for azure service bus?

Tags: serilog

The available sinks for serilog is located here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks

But it does not include azure service bus.

Is there currently an effort to creating one? If the answer is no, how hard is it to create one and how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at  Serilog.Sinks.AzureServiceBus.Alternate https://github.com/rahulruikar/serilog-sinks-azureservicebus

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.